# Parameters in R lines Function

Tags: r, plot, confidence-interval

I want to plot the 97% confidence interval and prediction interval into my other plot using different colours and legends. I want them to be represented by just straight lines across the scatter plot graph.

Please forgive me as I'm new to R so any tips also on how to phrase this question would be helpful!

I'm confused what to put in as the x and y coordinates in the lines function
I tried to put in a and m to match but it creates a very weird complicated graph that I'm sure is not correct, would you mind explaining what I should be putting inside the place where I put HELP in the code below?

```
attach(my_data)
plot(a, m,
     xlab="a", ylab = "m",
     main = "Confidence intervals and prediction intervals",
     ylim = c(10,50))
abline(lm.fit,lwd=5,col='pink')

p_pred <- predict(lm.fit,data.frame(a=c(14.50)),interval="prediction",level=0.97)
p_conf <- predict(lm.fit,data.frame(a=c(14.50)),interval="confidence",level=0.97)
lines(HELP,p_conf[,"lwr"], col="red", type="b", pch="+") 
lines(HELP,p_conf[,"upr"], col="red", type="b", pch="+")
lines(HELP,p_pred[,"upr"], col="blue", type="b", pch="*")
lines(HELP,p_pred[,"lwr"], col="blue", type="b", pch="*")
legend("bottomright",
       pch=c("+","*"),
       col=c("red","blue"),
       legend = c("confidence","prediction"))
```

I'm sure for this problem the solution is very simple, so I apologize as I am not that familiar with R if I am asking an easy question!

Answer (score 1):

If you want just plot you don't need to calculate predicitons yourself but you can use geom_smooth from ggplot2 library. As in the example below:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,cyl))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", level =0.97)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestions on the page! I actually ended up fixing the problem by creating a new variable that took the min and max value of the x variable and then the lines fitted on the graph.